# How difficult is it to reverse the sort order for different algorithms?

Tags: sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

Given the following sorting algorithms

- insertion sort
- selection sort
- merge sort

that sort elements in *ascending* order (smallest to largest). How difficult is it to modify each of the algorithms such that they sort the elements in *descending* order (largest to smallest) instead?

I have heard that it is equally difficult for each of them but I'd like to understand why this is so.

Comment: I can't explain. I just know that's the anwer.

Comment: Why is it equally difficult to reverse all of them I meant I couldn't explain the answer

Comment: The question was "for which of the sorting algorithms below is it most difficult to reverse the order of the sort from merge selection and insertion "

Comment: Ok, somebody understood what you mean. I have re-worded your question according to that answer. I hope it is this you've meant to ask. Feel free to edit again if not.

Answer (score 2):

They're all equally trivial to reverse as they are all [comparison sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort). At some point in those sorting algorithms there will be a comparison operation between a pair of elements such as:

```
if (a > b) ...
```

Making the algorithm sort in reverse order is as simple as changing the `>` to a `<`.

An implementation of a comparison sort can also use a separately implemented comparison function like the Java [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface, which is useful for making a sort implementation work with arbitrary data types. In that case, you can sort in reverse order by providing a comparator that returns the opposite result, without touching the sort algorithm itself.

And with any sort, you always have the option of implementing the reverse sort by simply reversing the data *after* the sort, which is a bit feeble but quite valid.

Comment: Oh dear, this was the question. I'll retract my close-vote then.

Comment: Note Java Comparator intefarce does not work with primitive types like int, you need to use object types like Integer.